# How to get Xml data by using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, extjs

I am trying to get my xml data by using ajax call. But I am getting only ROOT Node value data in my `result.responseXML`. Not able to access ITEM tag data.

My XML.

```
<ROOT UN="ABC" Total="28">
    <ITEM Val = "1" data = "name1" />
    <ITEM Val = "2" data = "name2" />
    <ITEM Val = "3" data = "name3" />
    <ITEM Val = "4" data = "name4" />
    <ITEM Val = "5" data = "name5" />
</ROOT>
```

Here is what I am trying.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function ( result, request )
            { 
               debugger;
                result.responseXML
            }
    });
```

In responseXML I am getting `<ROOT  UN="ABC" Total="28" ></ROOT>`

Can Anybody help me what I am doing wrong and how to coorrect that. How to get Item tag also.

Comment: Aren't all xml tags and attribute names meant to be lowercase? Why are there spaces between the attribute names, the equals sign, and the value?

Comment: First, look at the response in the Network tab of the developer tools (F12) to see what the actual response is.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nope. tag case is correct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes I checked this. sometime getting 400 error

Comment: @evolutionxbox XML is case-sensitive, but the user can determine the case of their own elements and attributes. Also, the extra spaces are perfectly valid.

Comment: My apologies, I'm so used to looking at HTML and XHTML.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No worries. FYI - if those tags and attributes were HTML, the uppercase and extra spaces would also be valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's bleugh. also, that downvote is not mine.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Perhaps, but still valid.

Answer (score 3):

In Ext js, the best way to read xml data is to use a store.

1. Create a store and define the fields (the mapping property (@Val) is used to indicate this is an attribute instead of a child element);
2. Use an ajax proxy to load the data;
3. Use an xml reader to read the data. In Ext js 6, you define the name of the root element and name of the elements you want to obtain;
4. Load the store and show the value of the first element in the console.

---

```
var itemStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [{name: 'val', mapping: '@Val'}, 
        {name: 'data', mapping: '@data'}],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.xml',
        method: 'GET',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'ITEM',
            rootProperty: 'ROOT'
        }
    }
});

itemStore.load(function(records, operation, success) {
    var item1 = itemStore.first();
    console.log("First item " + item1.get('val'));
});
```

---

Check the fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vd6

Comment: Thanks for answer. One question instead of field can I use reader.

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: b[(d.xtype || e)] is not a constructor error also by using `new Ext.data.Store` j.on is not a function error

Comment: In Ext js, you should use Ext.create('classname') instead of the new keyword. You can also use the store in a view for example, by using the 'store' configuration property.

Comment: What do you mean with reader? In the example above 'fields' is used to define the fields and properties, and the XML reader is used to read the data from the proxy and put it into the store. You can also create a model and use the model instead of fields. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-model