# Check if Ext Store returns empty

Tags: json, extjs, store

I have this problem where I want to check data store if it's empty or not. This data called by url function of store by JSON. Here is the code :

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    url : '/finance/report/type/'+type,
    autoLoad : true,
    reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader ({
        root : 'data',
        totalProperty : 'total',
        fields : [
            {name:'date'},
            {name:'requester'},
            {name:'status'},
        ]
    })
})
```

I want to get 'total' value of totalProperty. I've tried with store.getTotalCount, store.reader.jsonData.total, and others but either is undefined, 0, or error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When are you trying to access it? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: Basically, var store trigerred to create when I'm going to some page, and then after it is done, i want to read the store if it is empty or not. Version Ext Js 4

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your code in **load** listener and there you can get data returned from server.Add handler in store itself.

Comment: In load listener how to access totalproperty?

Comment: give some sample json which is returned from server.I will check.

Comment: @RayanSuryadikara Check here how to read. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894318/how-to-get-xml-data-by-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

To check if the store is empty, you can code as shown below.

```
store.on("load", function(){
   if(Ext.isEmpty(this.data.items)){ // Return true OR false
   }
});
```

To get the totalProperty

```
store.on("load", function(){
    var total = this.getTotalCount() //Returns total
});
```